# $u$ harmonic $\Rightarrow$ $u$ has the mean value property (proof question)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem (Gamelin; CA)

> If $u(z)$ is a harmonic function on a domain $D$, and if the disk $\{ |z-z_0| < \rho\}$ is contained in $D$, then
> $$
> u(z_0) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(z_0 + re^{i\theta})\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}, \quad 0 < r < \rho 
> $$

Proof (so far)

If $u$ is harmonic, then by Green's theorem,
$$
\oint_{|z-z_0| = r} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy = 0
$$
By parameterizing the circle using $x(t) = x_0 + r\cos(t)$ and $y(t) = y_0 + r \sin t $, we have
\begin{align}
0 & = r \int_0^{2\pi} \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin t \right] dt
\end{align}
which comes (I believe) by applying the equation: $\int_{\gamma} Pdx + Qdy = \int_a^b P(x(t),y(t))x'(t)dt + \int_a^b Q(x(t),y(t))y'(t)dt$.

Now here's where I'm confused, the integral equals $r \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(z_0 + re^{it})dt$. Where does this change of variable come from? I don't completely get why we are able to say,

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos t + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin t  = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(z_0 + re^{it})
$$

My attempt: By the chain rule,

\begin{align}
u_r(z_0 + re^{it}) = u_x(z_0 + re^{it})e^{it} + u_y(z_0 + re^{it})e^{it} \not = u_x(z_0 + re^{it})\cos(t) + u_y(z_0 + re^{it})\sin(t)??
\end{align}
since $e^{it} = cos(t) + i\sin(t)$

Thank you for your explanation

Take care,

Comment: You have to think of $u(z_0+re^{it})$ as $u(x_0+r\cos t, y_0+r\sin t)$ and apply Chain Rule from Calculus of two real variables.

Comment: thank you!! Appreciate it :)